# What does arc and chain mean in Ford Fulkerson 1956 paper?

Tags: graphs

[Ford Fulkerson 1956](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/lans/readings/routing/ford-max_flow-1956.pdf) uses words like "arcs" and "chains". What do they mean ?
Arc = path and chain = edge ?

Comment: The paper you linked is a paper of Ford and Fulkerson, not of Bellman and Ford.

Comment: I would like to ask you the following question: what is the reason to read a 65-year-old paper? There is a good chance that this paper provides the worst explanation of its ideas out of all explanations you can find on the Internet. Any 21 century textbook definitely explains them better.

Answer (score 2):

The paper litteraly gives the definition on the first page. An arc is a directed edge, and a chain is a directed simple path (*"does not intersect itself"*).

Comment: Is "directed" implied ? I *did* checkout the first page